# I want to search by other criteria, not by id (WEB API)

Tags: web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am total beginner in creating  WEB API.

I auto-generated models from database, and then controllers for every model, and my service works good with default settings.

For example:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(student))]
    public IHttpActionResult Getstudent(int id)
    {
        student student = db.students.Find(id);
        if (student == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(student);
    }
```

Now, when I call it using :
Localhost.../api/student/5
it returns correct data.

The problem is: I want to search by something else, not by ID (primary key), for example by username and password. 
I searched a lot and many people were talking about routing, new methods, what makes me so confused since I'm a beginner. 
If someone could help me, send me some tutorials or anything, I would be grateful.

this is my controller code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Web.Http;
    using System.Web.Http.Description;
    using studentsexams.Models;

    namespace studentsexams.Controllers
    {
        public class studentController : ApiController
        {
    private studentsEntities db = new studentsEntities();

    // GET api/student
    public IQueryable<student> Getstudents()
    {
        return db.students;
    }

    // GET api/student/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(student))]
    public IHttpActionResult Getstudent(int id)
    {
        student student = db.students.Find(id);
        if (student == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(student);
    }

    public student GetStudentByName(string name)
    {
        return StudentRepository.GetStudents().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == 1);
    }



    // PUT api/student/5
    public IHttpActionResult Putstudent(int id, student student)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != student.ids)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!studentExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST api/student
    [ResponseType(typeof(student))]
    public IHttpActionResult Poststudent(student student)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.students.Add(student);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (studentExists(student.ids))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = student.ids }, student);
    }

    // DELETE api/student/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(student))]
    public IHttpActionResult Deletestudent(int id)
    {
        student student = db.students.Find(id);
        if (student == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.students.Remove(student);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(student);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool studentExists(int id)
    {
        return db.students.Count(e => e.ids == id) > 0;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you want to Call the API action for GetStudentByName so you need to add routing in WebApiConfig.

**Like below Like:-**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "api/{controller}/{action}/{name}");

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "DefaultApi",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

**And add action in controller Like:-**

```
public Student GetStudentByName(string name)
    {
        return db.students.ToList().FirstOrDefault(s => s.StudentName == name); 
         //in this line just replace StudentName to your student name 
           //property of model class.
    }
```

**And Calling Part Like:-**

```
$.getJSON('/api/student/GetStudentByName/abc', function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {

        });
    });
```

So in this example you will be able to call GetStudentByName action with abc name.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. Do I have to define GetStudents() in my model? instead of StudentRepository - do I have to write name of my class (controller or model)?

Comment: If you define function in model so it will not possible to call as API.

Comment: I know, but I'm struggling with error. If I just copy paste this part of code into controller, it returns an error with studentRepository - "does not exists in current context". What to do?

Comment: This is in fact auto-generated code. I didn't insert anything except your piece of code.

Comment: Change code like return db.students.ToList().FirstOrDefault(s => s.StudentName == name); in this line just replace StudentName to your student name property of model class.

Comment: It sends me an error: Error 1 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<studentsexams.Models.student>' does not contain a definition for 'GetStudents' and no extension method 'GetStudents' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<studentsexams.Models.student>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: oh sorry please check it again.

Comment: It Works! Great! Thank you!!!I'l just copy your answer  as answer, just to help other people to find a solution when they need it!

Answer (score 0):

In controller we should add – **answered by Pragnesh Khalas:**

```
public Student GetStudentByName(string name)
{
return db.students.ToList().FirstOrDefault(s => s.StudentName == name); 
}
```

in this line just replace StudentName to your student name property of model class.

It works and it returns correct data!